# Datastore invalid value type for a Property with name

Tags: arrays, go, google-cloud-platform, properties, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to save an int64 array to Datastore using a PropertyList in GoLang.

Here is the Property in the PropertyList:
[image: Property in list]

However, I get this error:
[image: Error message]

I know you can store arrays in Datastore, especially of primitives. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, when trying to insert it via PropertyList. All my other properties get saved properly (they are just single primitives). The array is causing this issue.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the [`Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Property.Value) field? It does list the valid types. It also mentions that it accepts `[]interface{}`, so perhaps try converting your `[]int64` to `[]interface{}` and see if that's enough to make it work. https://go.dev/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: @mkopriva Ah, it looks like it takes in an `[]interface{}`, which supports the primitive data types. I will try convert my `[]int64` into `[]interface{}`, and see if it works. Thanks

Comment: @mkopriva It worked, 100%  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved! Thanks to [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) for the help.

If you want to save an array of any supported Datastore data type, you must append each element of that array into a new `interface{}` array.
[Value Field Documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Property.Value)

I wrote this reflect function to work with **any** slice type:

```
src := []int64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
value := reflect.ValueOf(src)
kind := value.Kind()
switch kind {
case reflect.Slice:
    interfaceArr := make([]interface{},0)
    for i := 0; i < value.Len(); i++ {
        interfaceArr = append(interfaceArr, value.Index(i).Interface())
    }
    return interfaceArr
}
```

Here is the correct way an Array Property should look in a Property List:
[image: Working Property]

Comment: This is the correct answer, and just to add to it Queries with the IN and NOT-IN operators also work this way. You can even see in the source code that the accepted type is []interface{}, otherwise it will return an error like "bad query filter value type: invalid Value type []string".

Here's the link to the source code: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/main/datastore/save.go

You can see the validation in func signature:
func interfaceToProto(iv interface{}, noIndex bool) (*pb.Value, error)

Comment: Couldn't fit the whole answer on top, so here's more. The way Queries work contradicts even google's own example of how to use IN, NOT-IN queries. You can see their example here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/4c97adb64b04a90ee6f41bee6d7fea95cbd10f86/datastore/snippets/query_in.go -- I guess they didn't test it?